# Is the .lib file generated for use with a .dll still a static library?

Tags: terminology

We've been having some debate in the office as to the names used to describe C++ .lib and .dlls

When creating a statically linked library, you end up with a .lib file.

When creating a dynamically linked library, you end up with a .lib and a .dll

Two questions:

1. Is the .lib file that's generated the same in both cases?
2. Is it fair to call the .lib file generated when creating a dynamically linked library a static library file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. No, the .lib file is not the same in both cases. You can see that from the file sizes: unless it's a very small library, the .lib file in the static case will be significantly larger than the .lib file in the dynamic case. The first one contains all code, the second only just enough for linking with the dll.
2. The .lib file generated when creating a dynamically linked library is normally called an import library. In a certain technical sense it is a static library file, but it's misleading to actually name it that way.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a DLL, as the name implies, you have to dynamically link to its functions. You do that by first calling `LoadLibrary` or `LoadLibraryX` to load its code into memory. Then, you call `GetProcAddress` to find the entry point to the function. You then cast the result of the proc address to a function pointer of the right kind, then call that function to do the stuff in the DLL. There are a few other steps I left out, but the gist is that there are several hoops to jump through to call the DLL functions.

Or, you use the .lib file, which does all that behind the scene, loads the DLL on startup, and lets you pretend the calls to the DLL are the same as any other function call.

If you link against the lib, but don't deploy the DLL, your program will explode, because the `LoadLibrary` call behind the scenes will fail and your program will be unable to startup.